# extract duplicate lines in regex

Tags: regex

How to extract duplicate lines in regex

For Example,

```
KB4494507
16.0.11337.12110
KB4494507
16.0.11337.12110
KB4498509
```

Result:

```
KB4494507
16.0.11337.12110
KB4498509
```

tried but no luck
`(.+)(\n\1)+`
`(.*)(\r?\n\1)+`
`(.*)[\r\n]*(\r?\n\1)+`
`(.*)(?:(?:\r?\n|\r)\1)+`

Comment: Does it have to be regex?

Comment: `KB4498509` is not repeated here. See https://regex101.com/r/W9vnqq/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
(.*\n.*\n)\1
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/q6P7uB/1). In `Javascript`, this could be:

```js
const regex = /(.*\n.*\n)\1/gm;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('(.*\\n.*\\n)\\1', 'gm')

const str = `KB4494507
16.0.11337.12110
KB4494507
16.0.11337.12110
KB4498509
`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: it doesn't work when it comes like KB4494507 
16.0.11337.12110 
KB4498509 
16.0.11337.12110 
KB4494507
or

KB4494507 
16.0.11337.12110 
KB4498509 
16.0.11337.12110

Comment: @Kalpesh check here https://tools.waytolearnx.com/en/regex-tester/36cb28035308 scroll down to **Substitution**